# Adding text to texture - Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, textures, kivy

I want to add a few text fields defined by a user to an image and export is as one `.png` file.
I thought of just making screenshot of whole widget but that's low quality and it's not what I'm realling looking into.
For now I have code:

```
kv = '''

PageLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    RelativeLayout:
        Image:
            pos:10,10
            id: template
            source: 'template.png'

        Label: 
            pos: 50,50
            markup: True
            text: 'Test'           

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Configure'
            on_release: app.open_settings()
        Button:
            id: savebtn      
            text: 'Save' 
            on_release: app.sc()
'''
```

And is it better to write it in kv language or python?

Thanks for any input!